# Configure bond using mode=4 (802.3ad)

Tags: networking, bonding, interface, debian-jessie

I have a Debian 8 system with two NICs I want to bond. My managed switch is already configured to link aggregate the two ports I'm using.

On the linux box, I have installed `ifenslave`.

In /etc/network/interfaces, I have:

```
 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet manual
    bond-master bond0

 auto eth1
 iface eth1 inet manual
    bond-master bond0

 auto bond0
 iface bond0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.100
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    gateway 10.0.0.1
    slaves eth0 eth1
    bond-mode 4
    bond-miimon 100
    bond_downdelay 200
    bond_updelay 300
```

Edit: Looks like the config is wrong when using mode 4. I'm having a hard time finding examples of how to configure 802.3ad.

Edit 2: I tried modprobe bonding mode=4 and now cat /proc/net/bond0 is showing 802.3ad however my entire network becomes unreachable.

Comment: you need to configure the lacp on your switch first to use mode 4

Answer (score 1):

The switch needs to support 802.3ad. It's a protocol where the switch is talking to server's interfaces to see if they are really in one bond. Quite often switches are incompatible with Linux implementation. In this case don't use `mode=802.3ad`, for example use `mode=balance-alb`.